# Why is there a counter on tensorflow placeholders even for same variables?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

Following experiment in Tensorflow 1.8 with iPython console:

```
In [2]: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, [None, 784])
   ...: y = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, [None, 10])
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [3]: x
Out[3]: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 784) dtype=float16>

In [4]: y
Out[4]: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float16>

In [5]: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, [None, 784])
   ...: y = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, [None, 10])

In [6]: x
Out[6]: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?, 784) dtype=float16>

In [7]: y
Out[7]: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float16>
```

Why the this "placeholder counter" exist and what is the reason for it? I reassign the variables with the same placeholders, so I wonder why they are not numbered again as "Placeholder:0" and "Placeholder_1:0" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you run `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, [None, 784])`, the op gets added to the default graph. You can check by:

```
for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
   print (op.name)
#Placeholder
#Placeholder_1
#Placeholder_2
```

So in `ipython notebook` you can do `tf.reset_default_graph()` before a cell to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it works. Still, why do they get duplicated and not simply overwritten (as I would like to because I name the placeholders with the same names "x" and "y"? And why are they added to the default graph as "operations" and not as "operands" as x and y are clearly two operands and a operation has not even been declared yet?

Comment: `x` and `y` are just Python variable names. They have nothing to do with the objects assigned to them. If you assign `x = tf.some_op` multiple times, each time will create the op anew. They will not be "garbage collected" either because they are now part of the computation graph. Note if you want to give a name to the placeholder op, it has a `name` argument you can supply.